# Why isn't my UICollectionViewCell updating?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am checking to see if the indexPath of my cell is divisible by 7 when tapping on ti. If it is, the cell is supposed to change background colors. I believe my code is correct, but nothing is happening!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell: CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    if (indexPath.row + 1) % 7 == 0 {
        print("true")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 133/255, blue: 211/255, alpha:1.0)
    }

}
```

I'm getting the true message, but the cell is not updating. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not dequeue another cell is like asking a new one, just use `func cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?`

> **Parameters** indexPath   The index path that specifies the section and
>   item number of the cell. 
> **Return Value** The cell object at the
>   corresponding index path or nil if the cell is not visible or
>   indexPath is out of range.